# SPARQL Problems filtering DateTimes

Tags: datetime, xsd, sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I have some RDF data in a Virtuoso repository, and I am trying to filter results by xsd:dateTime. I have read many threads with similar issues ere and in other forums, but I cannot find the correct answer.

Here is my data:

[image]

As can be seen, the **?xsddt** variable gets the xsd:dateTime value in a valid format (http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html). (I have also tried with other xsd.DateTime formats including time zones etc but it does not work).

Here is the SPARQL query I am using:

```
PREFIX owl-time: <http://www.w3.org/2006/time#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
select ?instant ?year ?xsddt
FROM <urn:calendarData>
WHERE {
  ?instant  owl-time:hasDateTimeDescription ?dtdesc.
  ?dtdesc owl-time:year ?year.
  ?dtdesc owl-time:inXSDDateTime ?xsddt.
 FILTER (?year = "2014" 
    && ?xsddt > "2014-02-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime)
}
```

**?xsddt > "2014-02-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime** is the part that is giving me problems.

Any idea of how can I fix this problem and be able to filter results by dateTime??

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Data sample (sorry for the inconveniences):

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:owl-time="http://www.w3.org/2006/time#"
...
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2006/time#3/15/15_3">
    <owl-time:hasDateTimeDescription rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <owl-time:year>2015</owl-time:year>
      <owl-time:month>3</owl-time:month>
      <owl-time:dayOfYear>74</owl-time:dayOfYear>
      <owl-time:week>11</owl-time:week>
      <owl-time:dayOfWeek>sunday</owl-time:dayOfWeek>
      <owl-time:day>15</owl-time:day>
      <owl-time:unitType>unitDay</owl-time:unitType>
      <owl-time:hour>3</owl-time:hour>
      <owl-time:inXSDDateTime>2015-03-15T03:00:00</owl-time:inXSDDateTime>
</owl-time:hasDateTimeDescription>
<rdf:type>http://www.w3.org/2006/time#Instant</rdf:type>


 </rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Just because ?xsddt is in the right format doesn't necessarily mean it is an xsd:dateTime. Try explicitly converting it

Comment: If you do the select without the `FILTER`, you should see `^^xsd:dateTime` on the `?xsddt` values -- *if* they're actually of this type. `CAST`/`CONVERT` or similar, or a modified `FILTER`, may bring the results you want.

Comment: That said... Virtuoso-specific questions often get better and faster response through Virtuoso-specific channels, like [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp)

Comment: Without seeing your data, we don't know that you've actually got xsd:dateTimes.  You might just have strings which are (legal) lexical forms for xsd:dateTime literals, but without actually having datatyped literals.  Plus, anyone who can't view images has **no idea** what your data is.  Please provide actual data that we can work with.  The fact that you're filtering with `?year = "2014"` and not `?year = 2014` makes me think that you may not actually be using typed literals, but just strings with (correct) lexical forms.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor That was the first thing a looked into: the OWL Time ontology has no range for `owl-time:year`, thus, it should be an RDF plain literal and `owl-time:inXSDDateTime` has as range `xsd:dateTime`. So it depends on whether the user also considered to follow this ontology and added datatypes if necessary.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor @AKSW I am kind of new to the ontology modelling and RDF... and even though I read books etc. I am having some problems like the one I explained above. I have casted some of the query results, doing something like `FILTER (<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>(?year) >= 2016`. However, same thing is not working with **xsd:dateTime** . If I understood you correctly, I should explicitly somehow declare that the value of <owl-time:inXSDDateTime> is of xsd:dateTime type?? Isn't it enough being defined in the owl-time ontology??

Comment: @havor it looks like your data is using plain literals everywhere, not typed literals.

Comment: @havor -- Ontologies do not enforce data types, they merely advise them.  I believe that for your query to work as you wish, you need to either change your data to somethng like `<owl-time:inXSDDateTime>"2015-03-15T03:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime</owl-time:inXSDDateTime>` *or* change your query to something like `FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?xsddt) > "2014-02-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime )`.